# Set minimum value on chart axis using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Can you help me with this? I want to generate a minimum axis value for my chart based on a cell reference.

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
   With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
       .MinimumScale = Worksheets("Chart Data").Range("E111").Value
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What issue are you actually having - is it not working, do you get an error...?

Comment: Hello Alex. Thank you for your response. I am having an error of 

"Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set"

What I actually have is 2 sheets, 1: is the chart data which I put all the data for the chart, 2: is where the chart is.

Comment: You don't identify the `ActiveChart`. You need to write: `With Worksheets("Sheet2").ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)`. That worked for me.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
    With Worksheets("Chart").ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
    .MinimumScale = Worksheets("Chart Data").Range("E111").Value
    End With
End Sub

Is this how it is? I got an error: "Run-time eror 438: Object doesn't support this property or method."

Comment: How is `E111` getting calculated? The issue is with `ActiveChart`. If you are in `Chart Data` when the calculation happens then you get an error as the chart is not *active*. Instead, try referencing the chart directly by name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_calculate()
    Dim cht As Chart

    Set cht = Worksheets("Chart").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

    cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Worksheets("Chart Data").Range("E111").Value
End Sub
```

- Set up a reference to your chart object so you don't need
  `ActiveChart`
- You may need to update `ChartObjects("Chart 1")` with the name of
  your chart
- You can also index it so if you only have one chart on the page you
  can use `ChartObjects(1)`

Comment: Hello. On the cell "Chart Data" E111, I get the minimum date and pass the value to the minimum axes using the general format value.

I try using your code with ChartObjects and its good it throws no error but the minimum axis is not updating. I try to check it manually and it says 0.0

Comment: Thank you Alex. I got it now. I used a button to trigger run the vba. Thanks a lot.